# Alternative ways to start hadoop streaming job

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-streaming

I can sucessfully kick of a hadoop streaming job from the terminal but i am looking for ways to start steaming jobs via an api, eclipse or some other means.

The closest i found was this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11564463/remotely-execute-hadoop-streaming-job but it has no answers!

Any ideas or suggestions would be welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question, I found a way to do this, hopefully this will help you too.

First method should work on Hadoop 0.22:

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://xxxxx:9000");
conf.set("mapred.job.tracker", "hdfs://xxxxx:9001");
StreamJob sj = new StreamJob();
try {
    ToolRunner.run(conf, sj, new String[] { 
                "-D", "stream.tmpdir=c:\\",
                "-mapper", "/path/to/mapper.py",
                "-reducer", "/path/to/reducer.py", "-input",
                "/path/to/input", "-output",
                "/path/to/output" });
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I also found [this Java wrapper](https://github.com/lohitvijayarenu/hadoop-common/blob/trunk/hadoop-tools/hadoop-streaming/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/streaming/HadoopStreaming.java) which you should be able to run.

Comment: I am trying to do as you have said here, but I get back exit code 5. Any idea how to interpret that?

Comment: Never mind. My problem was adding the right dependencies and then include map-red.xml and yarn-site.xml into my YarnConfiguration.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Apache Oozie](http://oozie.apache.org/) - once you have defined your job via XML you can launch a job via an Http POST to the oozie server

Answer (score 0):

When the Hadoop streaming job is run as

> hadoop jar /home/training/Installations/hadoop-1.0.3/contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-1.0.3.jar -input input4 -output output4 -mapper /home/training/Code/Streaming/max_temperature_map.rb -reducer /home/training/Code/Streaming/max_temperature_reduce.rb

then [org.apache.hadoop.streaming.HadoopStreaming](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/trunk/hadoop-tools/hadoop-streaming/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/streaming/HadoopStreaming.java) is executed. This class is defined in the MANIFEST.MF in the hadoop-streaming-1.0.3.jar. Check the code in the [org.apache.hadoop.streaming.HadoopStreaming](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/trunk/hadoop-tools/hadoop-streaming/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/streaming/HadoopStreaming.java) java class to know the API details.