# Running Streaming job in hadoop using Java Apis

Tags: java, hadoop, hadoop-streaming

I am new to hadoop and learning about streaming jobs.
Can anybody guide me regarding how to run Streaming Jobs through Java code?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to run Java code using the streaming API, you can directly pass the class name as the mapper and/or reducer. Something like this:

```
$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop  jar $HADOOP_HOME/hadoop-streaming.jar \
-input myInputDirs \
-output myOutputDir \
-mapper com.something.MyMapper \
-reducer com.something.MyReducer
```

However if you want to run only Java code, I would advise going through the regular Java API instead of using Hadoop streaming, it's much more flexible.

It was not clear to me if your question was about running Java code in streaming, or if you want to start a streaming code by invoking it from Java. I assumed you want to run Java code above, but if it's the other option, you could just start a subprocess from Java to run a command-line utility, for example:

```
String cmd = "/usr/bin/hadoop  jar /path/to/hadoop-streaming.jar -input myinput -output myoutput -mapper mymapper.sh -reducer myreducer.sh";
String[] cmdSplit = cmd.split(" ");
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmdSplit);
pb.start();
```

You could also do the same by adding hadoop-streaming jar in your classpath and calling:

```
String cmd = "/usr/bin/hadoop  jar /path/to/hadoop-streaming.jar -input myinput -output myoutput -mapper mymapper.sh -reducer myreducer.sh";
String[] cmdSplit = cmd.split(" ");
HadoopStreaming.main(cmdSplit);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Charles! :) I wanted to invoke streaming code by invoking it from Java. Sorry if I was not clear.

Comment: Hi Charles, do we have have something like HadoopStreaming for running pig job script as well?

Comment: @Ajn There is something like `PigServer` or `PigRunner`, but you should probably create another question for that since it's a pretty different problem, I can give you a more detailed idea there.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at using ToolRunner to run your Hadoop Streaming code if you are looking to invoke it in Java. It will allow you the flexibility of invoking hadoop streaming from a non-hadoop node.

```
JobConf conf = new JobConf();
conf.set("fs.default.name", "hdfs://hadoop-worker-node:54310");
conf.set("mapred.job.tracker", "hadoop-worker-node:54311");

StreamJob sj = new StreamJob();

String cmdArgs = "-file mymapper.sh -file myreducer.sh -input myinput -output myoutput -mapper mymapper.sh -reducer myreducer.sh";
String[] cmdArgsSplit = cmdArgs.split(" ");

int jobReturnCode = ToolRunner.run(conf, sj, cmdArgsSplit);
```

The files specified by the -file arguments (e.g. mappers and reducers), as well as the hadoop streaming runtime classes, will be packaged in a jar and sent through to the jobtracker. This has the advantage of zero-deployment to the hadoop node before running the job.

EDIT: I just realised this is very similar to the example Charles [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14248897/1430548) in another thread a couple of weeks ago :)